# rolling up multiple rows in a single row in a colum order in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

How can I return multiple rows with the same values into a single row as comma separated and combined in ascendant order in a single column (in SQL server)?

**Table2**

```
------------
col1 | col2 | col3
----------------------
1    | line1 | 2
1    | line2 | 1
1    | line3 | 4
2    | line4 | 1
2    | line5 | 3
2    | line6 | 2  
3    | line7 | 2
3    | line8 | 1
```

**Desired result in ascendant order according to col3:**

```
Col1 |  col2
----------------------------
1    | Line2,Line1,Line3
2    | Line4,Line6,Line5
3    | Line8,Line7
```

Comment: which RDMS are you using? And it doesn't look like you are using table 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting of sql server queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885737/formatting-of-sql-server-queries)

Comment: Now it is more clear I think, I have updated the question :)

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle? What version?

Comment: The rdbms is SQL server

Comment: Curious, why do you want comma separated values *within* a column? How does that help in any reporting or analysis needs.

Comment: Good question. I need to locate the ones that have no data as a category for a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

```
select Col1, string_agg(Col2, ',') within group(order by Col3)
from Table2
group by Col1
```

Comment: @SQL_NewUser It is working for me. Maybe you want desc sort order, in which case you can make the following change (order by Col3 desc).